# What is this discarded exoskeleton from?

Tags: species-identification, invertebrates

This morning I was looking round the garden and found this sticking out of a pit in patch of soil, next to the wall of the house (in a trough sort of thing). I came to the conclusion it must be part of an insects exoskeleton that was discarded or part of a pupae. Can anybody identify what this belongs to? My location is in the south-west (Wiltshire region) of Great Britain. I'm just interested in what exactly I've found!

[image: Close up of markings]
[image: Different angle]
[image: Size comparison to a 50p piece!]

Answer (score 2):

I can't be certain, but it is probably the pupal shell of a [crane fly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crane_fly) (daddy longlegs, *Tipula palidosa*). [Here is an image to compare](http://lastrefuge.co.uk/php/show-images-all-big.php?id=CHI0920), and you can find lots more with a Google image search.

In the UK at least, these are colloquially referred to as leatherjackets and if you find one in soil before the adult has emerged it will often twitch.

Comment: I think it's a moth: http://www.uksafari.com/buried_treasure.htm

Comment: I very much doubt this specimen and the photo you refer to are tipulid pupae. They look more like [this one](http://www.arkive.org/cranefly/tipula-paludosa/image-A20695.html)